# Spectrum of non-diagonalizable matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Consider a **non diagonalizable** square matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$, and consider its distinct eigenvalues **counted only once** $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \ldots, \lambda_L \in \mathbb{C}$, with $1 \leq L < N$ (the non diagonalizability of $A$ implies that $L$ is strictly lower than $N$).

For each of the previous eigenvalue, we can find at least one eigenvector. The eigenvectors are $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_L \in \mathbb{C}^{N}$.

Now consider the matrix $$B = A - \eta I,$$

with $\eta \in \mathbb{R}$.

If we multiply $B$ by an eigenvector $v_j$ of $A$, we get the following:

$$Bv_j = Av_j - \eta v_j = (\lambda_j - \eta) v_j.$$

This means that $\lambda_1-\eta, \lambda_2-\eta, \ldots, \lambda_L-\eta \in \mathbb{C}$
are also eigevalues of $B$, and  $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_L \in \mathbb{C}^{N}$
are the corresponding eigenvectors.

The question is:

> Can I say that $\lambda_1-\eta, \lambda_2-\eta, \ldots, \lambda_L-\eta \in
> \mathbb{C}$ are the unique eigenvalues of $B$? 
>   Can there be other eigenvalues of $B$?

**Motivation of the question**

If $\lambda_1-\eta, \lambda_2-\eta, \ldots, \lambda_L-\eta \in
\mathbb{C}$ are the unique eigenvalues of $B$, then I can choose $\eta$ such that the real part of each eigenvalue of $B$ is negative, i.e.

$$ \eta > \mathcal{Re}(\lambda_q),$$

such that $$\mathcal{Re}(\lambda_q) = \max_{i=1, \ldots, L} \mathcal{Re}(\lambda_i) .$$

If there are more eigenvalues than the listed, then I can't be sure of choice of $\eta$.

Comment: Why do you think that $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_L$ are eigenvalues of $B$?

Comment: @Hyperplane sorry, Arnaud Mortier fixed this. It was just a copy-and-paste error. The eigenvalues of $B$ are $\lambda_1-\eta, \lambda_2-\eta, \ldots, \lambda_L-\eta$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes, as can be seen immediately using the characterisation that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of a matrix $M$ if and only if $\det(M-\lambda \operatorname{Id}_N)=0$.

In fact, if the list of distinct eigenvalues of a matrix $M\in \mathcal{M}_{N\times N}(\mathbb{C})$ is $\lambda_1, \ldots,\lambda_k $ then the list of eigenvalues of $(M-\lambda \operatorname{Id}_N)$ is $\lambda_1-\lambda, \ldots,\lambda_k -\lambda$, and this is true for literally any matrix, diagonalisable or not.

Now to answer your question in the comments, if $B$ was diagonalisable, you would get $$P(A-\eta \operatorname{Id})P^{-1}=D$$
where $D$ is some diagonal matrix, therefore
$$PAP^{-1}=D+\eta \operatorname{Id}$$
would be diagonal as well which is impossible. Note that we used the fact that $\operatorname{Id}$ commutes with any matrix (here $P$).

Comment: Thanks a lot, your words confirm my thoughts. Besides all, we can also conclude that $B$ is non diagonalizable too for any $\eta \in \mathbb{R}$, right?

Comment: @the_candyman Yes - I edited my answer accordingly. But note that it is not *that* straightforward (it doesn't follow from just looking at the spectrum).

Comment: Everything is clearer now. Many thanks

Comment: My pleasure :).